# how to make that every 10 sec automatically change the program background

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

how to make that every 10 sec automatically change the program background
and the colors will be randomly selected

```
color = (random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
```

update:

i want use in this code:

```
app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title = "test con", size=(800,300) ) 
window.SetMaxSize(wx.Size(800,300))
window.SetMinSize(wx.Size(800,300))
window.SetIcon(wx.Icon("eq.ico"))
window.SetBackgroundColour(color)
panel = wx.Panel(window, wx.ID_ANY)     
suka = bat()

def on_timer():
    label1aa.SetLabel(str(ram_uz()))
    label8.SetLabel(doi)
    label16.SetLabel(str(random.randint(1,100)))
    label1a.SetLabel(str(bat()))
    wx.CallLater(1000, on_timer)
panel.SetBackgroundColour(color)
panel.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))
```

Comment: `module 'threading' has no attribute 'thread'` but it does have a `Thread` attribute! Note the capital `T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this i hope it will help you

```
import threading
def change_color():
     while True:
          time.sleep(10)
          color = (random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
threading.Thread(target=change_color).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer:

```
import threading

timer = threading.Timer(interval, function) 
//interval is the lapse of time you want between each execution of the function "function"
timer.start()
```